# prolate cycloid body movement

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d, physics, curve

How can I make a box2d body move along a prolate cycloid curve? I've searched extensively and haven't found anything leads. Below is an example of how the movement should look like. I would appreciate any help.

[image: prolate cycloid]

Comment: perhaps you were searching for complete source code? The formula is readily available, this came up on top by a google search: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProlateCycloidEvolute.html

Comment: @LearnCocos2D: thanks. I have used the formula but I am not getting the expected movement. The y value just decreases for every x as the body moves